# Excel - Return average of right three values in array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

If I have a range in excel, say A2:I2, that is used to store the results from a monthly competition, what formula do I use in excel to return the average of the three most right values?
The formula needs to account for not all columns being filled, i.e. one player might have 5 results, one might have 9, and one might have 1.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combinedly use `TEXTJOIN()` and `FILTERXML()` like below.

```
=AVERAGE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,B2:J2)&"</s></t>","//s[position()>" & COUNTA(B2:J2)-3 &"]"))
```

[image]

- Here `"<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,B2:J2)&"</s></t>"` will construct a valid `XML` string.
- `XPATH` parameter `"//s[position()>" & COUNTA(B2:J2)-3 &"]"` will return last 3 nodes to calculate `Average` by `AVERAGE()` function.
- `COUNTA(B2:J2)-3` will detect how many nodes have before last 3 nodes so that we can return rest of nodes means always last 3 nodes by `FILTERXML()` formula.

More about `FILTERXML()` here by JvdV [Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747)

> Edit: For google sheet you can use below formula.

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B2:J2,(COLUMN(B2:J2)-Column(A2))>IF(COUNTA(B2:J2)<=3,0,COUNTA(B2:J2)-3)))
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks!  Is there a comparable formula for google sheets as I have to do the same thing there as well

Comment: You can also use: `=AVERAGE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,B2:J2)&"</s></t>","//s[position()>=last()-3]"))`

Comment: @JvdV It `//s[position()>=last()-3]` returns 4 node while `//s[position()>=last()-2]` return 3 nodes from last. So, I think `//s[position()>=last()-2]` this will be correct.

Answer (score 2):

If one has Microsoft365, you could also use:

[image]

Formula in `K2`:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(SORTBY(FILTER(B2:J2,B2:J2<>""),SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B2:J2)),-1),SEQUENCE(MIN(3,COUNT(B2:J2)))))
```